# Enter values of attributes of a new example to predict its label to RapidMiner Process using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, knn, rapidminer

i have a simple KNN process which takes an excel dataset as the training data, i can run it from inside NetBeans and display the accuracy of the model generated by it , my question is : How can i enter values for a new example "without entering the label value of course which i want to predict" from inside NetBeans...then displaying the result of this predicted example's label after applying the model on it

thank you in advance